# how to get data from wcf service using WCDL2OBJC

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

hi i got project files using `WCDL2OBJC`, and included it in my project.
but i don't know how to give inputs and get data, i am blank here can not move forward.

were as my url:

```
[http://parentportal.technologyorg.com/ParentPortal.svc?wsdl][1]
```

and i want to pass the parameter `studentID='E6A83233-7D7F-49AF-B54E-375BBF3E3E59'` to this url and get the out put in IBAction from the files of WSDL2OBJC.

can any one have some examples or source code to do this.
i have `@class GetSchoolEvents`, which is my method to get data in `WCDL2OBJC` file. how to access this and get data?

Answer (score 0):

On the WSDL2OBJC pages you can find some samples how you can use the generated code. http://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/wiki/UsageInstructions
Just create a ..OperationRequest object and set properties for the variables